Using oidc-provider for login using a /login endpoint
I am trying to implement my own api route which uses oidc internally. I have created a login route which takes username, password and scopes(optional) as input. Using them i am creating a token based on the given scopes. Then i am saving the generated token in user database.
However to generate a new token the user has to login again, giving the same username and password. To avoid this and make a single click login feature, I have implemented jwt and stored the data in cookie. so there is no need to give username and password again. I want to know is there a way without using cookies to generate new tokens for the user so that s/he don't have to give credentials again. Basically is there an in-build oidc-provider feature that can handle all of that of it's own. The user only have to give pass/username only once and new scopes can be requested invidually. Just like google's OAuth.
I am using nestjs and oidc-provider^8.4.6 and this is my code:
@Post('/login')
  async loginRoute(
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Res() res: Response,
    @Body('username') username: string,
    @Body('password') password: string,
    @Body('scopes') scopes: string,
  ) {
    //console.log('1');
    const jwtToken = req.cookies?.jwt;
    if (!jwtToken && (!username || !password)) {
      res.status(400).send({
        error: 'Invalid Credentials',
        error_description: 'username, password missing in body',
      });
      return;
    }
    //console.log('2');
    const user = jwtToken
      ? await this.jwtService.verifyAsync(jwtToken, { secret: 'secret' })
      : await this.prismaService.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            username,
            password,
          },
        });
    //console.log('3');
    if (!user) {
      res.status(401).send({
        error: 'Invalid Credentials',
        error_description:
          "User with the given username and password doesn't exist",
      });
      return;
    }
    //console.log('4');

    const finalScope = scopes ? scopes : 'openid';
    //console.log(scopes);
    let headersList = {
      Accept: '*/*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      Authorization: 'Basic YXBwOmFfc2VjcmV0',
    };

    let bodyContent = `grant_type=client_credentials&scope=${finalScope}`;

    let reqOptions = {
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/oidc/token',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headersList,
      data: bodyContent,
    };

    let response = await axios.request(reqOptions);
    //console.log(response.data);

    await this.userService.insertToken(
      user.id,
      response.data.access_token,
    );

    if (!jwtToken) {
      const token = await this.jwtService.signAsync(
        {
          id: user.id,
          sub: response.data.access_token,
        },
        { secret: 'secret' },
      );
      res.cookie('jwt', token);
    } else {
      res.cookie('jwt', jwtToken);
    }
    //console.log(val);
    return res.send(response.data);
  }

